# Access keys within Javascript object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an iframe that I am sending a data object to that has an id_token and access_token in it. The data object arrives fine and I am able to pull the object with an event listener. Sample code is below. However, when I receive the object I try to access items in the object and get an undefined. I have included an obfiscated image of the object that I receive in the javascript console.

I have included snippets of different things I have tried but to no avail.

Displaying the iframe

```
const data = {
    id_token: idToken,
    access_token: accessToken
};
```

Application that is being displayed in the iframe

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);

  function receiveMessage(event) {
    if (event.origin !== 'https://example.com") {
      return;
    }

    let eventData = event.data;
    console.log(eventData); // The response is the object that is returned in the image below
    console.log(eventData.id_token) // The response is undefined
    console.log(eventData[id_token]) // undefined
    console.log(eventData["id_token"] // undefined
    console.log(eventData['"id_token"'] // undefined

    // All three of these displayed each individual character of the object.
    Object.keys(eventData).forEach(key => console.log(key, eventData[key]));

    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(eventData).forEach(key =>
      console.log(key, eventData[key])
    );

    for (let key in eventData) console.log(key, eventData[key]);
  }
}, []);
```

Basically I need to extract the access and id tokens for authentication. If there is a better way to do this I am all ears.

Screenshot of object that is being returned:
[image]

Comment: Can you please add a visible screenshot?  This console.log(eventData[id_token]) and this console.log(eventData["'id_token'"]) won't work BTW.

Comment: Where's `eventData` coming from?

Comment: The screenshot is visible. The obfiscated data are keys. The data looks like {"id_token": "string", "access_token": "string"}

Comment: Are you sure you are passing an object and not JSON?. Try eventDataObject = JSON.Parse(eventData)

Comment: @John I will give that a try. It is being created as an object but no telling. Still pretty green. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @john that was it! Move your comment to an answer and I'll mark it solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When receiving "objects" from requests or events in Javascript it can be easy to mistake actual objects from a string-serialized form of an object in JSON notation.

It can be difficult to tell which is which when logging to the console as the example shows but browser-tools can be more helpful as the image shows.

If you need to convert your JSON back to an object then use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and handle any exceptions.

```js
obj = {a:100}
json = JSON.stringify(obj);

// print an object
console.log('Printing an Object:')
console.log(obj)

// print json
console.log('Printing a JSON string:')
console.log(json)
```

[image]